# Extracting images that are not in the Docker registry

Tags: docker, registry, docker-registry

I set up a machine for the Docker registry and did the configuration. But I want an image that is not in the docker registry to be automatically pulled from docker'hub. If possible, these images should also be saved in the registry environment. Nexus does this. But I'm wondering if this is possible on the docker registry.